# PrestaShop: Saving Manufacturers

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I asked this same question on the official forums but received no response. Not sure if anyone here is experienced with PrestaShop but here is my issue.

I need to add an extra field in the manufacturer edit/add tab, I was able to do this by overriding renderForm in AdminManufacturersController.php like this:

```
public function renderForm()
{
    global $shopOptions;
    $this->fields_form_override = array(
         array(
             'type' => 'checkbox',
             'label' => 'Shop',
             'name' => 'shop_select',
             'desc' => 'Choose The Shops This Manufacturer Applies To',
             'values' => array(
                 'query' => $shopOptions, >> comes from array filled by db query in __construct
                 'id' => 'id',
                 'name' => 'name'
             ),
         ),
     );
    return parent::renderForm();

}
```

This works and I am now trying to find the update and create functions for a manufacturer. When editing the product classes, you can easily spot set functions like setQuantity in StockAvailable.php.

I have ssh access to the server so I was able to dig deeper with grep, to no avail. It seems like it uses some sort of function to auto insert into the database whilst some classes use a plain old execute with a normal query.

Any ideas on where this could be found?

Answer (score 0):

On Prestashop 1.6.x you do not need to amend any function for it to have CRUD functionalities. You just need to add it in :

- RenderForm (like you already did)
- Add the variable in the manufacturer class (Manufacturer.php) like `public $shop_select;`
- Add it in the `public static $definition` array in the manufacturer class
- Add the column in manufacturer or manufacturer_lang table depending on whether your field is a lang field.

Cheers :)